# Find expected value of a game

Tags: probability, expected-value

A and B play sudoku until A has 3 consecutive win. Find expected value of the number of matches that they played. Known that there are three cases: win, tie, lose and the probability is uniform.

I've tried using recursion approach such that:
Assume f(x) is the probability that A has 3 consecutive win in x matches. We have:

$f(3) = (\frac{1}{3})^3$
$f(4) = (\frac{2}{3})(\frac{1}{3})^3$
$f(5) = (\frac{2}{3})(\frac{1}{3})^3$
$f(6) = (\frac{2}{3})(\frac{1}{3})^3$

For x > 6, assume $x = 3*n + m$ $(m = 1,2,3)$, we have:

$f(x) = (1-f(3))^{n-1}*f(m+3)$

Then, expected value is:

$E = 3*f(3)+4f(4)+5f(5)+6f(6)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(3k+3)(1-f(3))^{n-1}f(6)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(3k+1)(1-f(3))^{n-1}f(4)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(3k+2)(1-f(3))^{n-1}f(5)=166$

The expected value is too large. Is my solution wrong?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This is a question-and-answer site. Please ask a question rather than telling us what to do in the imperative mood.

Comment: What is a sudoku match?